# Bokeh chart set x axis label

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

I m building a charts page using bokeh to plot them. I have some Line chart where I need to plot on x-axis the number of week of the year.

So this is the result that I m able to build:
[image]

As you can see there are some poin on X axis with 09/2023 and 10/2023 at last point.

It is possible to display only the point where are the values, like this?
[image]

This is the code I used to build this chart:

```
plotIndicatori = figure(plot_width=int(850), plot_height=int(165),
                               tools="pan,box_zoom,reset",
                               title=nomeIndicatore,
                            x_axis_type="datetime")
            plotIndicatori.toolbar.logo = None
            plotIndicatori.y_range.start = 0
            plotIndicatori.y_range.end = rangeMax + 5
            plotIndicatori.line(x='DateTime', y='Valore', color="navy", alpha=1, source=sourceIndicatori)
            plotIndicatori.circle(x='DateTime', y='Valore', color="navy", alpha=1, source=sourceIndicatori)
            # plotSfera.axis.visible = False
            plotIndicatori.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
            plotIndicatori.outline_line_color = background
            plotIndicatori.border_fill_color = background
            plotIndicatori.background_fill_color = background
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Answer (score 0):

The [`DatetimeTickFormatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.DatetimeTickFormatter) from bokeh offers you multiple options to format the date string on your x-axis. The options `%U`, `%V`  and `%W`all offer the number of weeks. You have to select the one that works best for you. Read the docs to get the complete list of available options.

##### Minimal Example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'data':list(range(367))},
    index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01', freq='D')
)

from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=300, height=300, x_axis_type='datetime')
p.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%U", months="%m %U")
p.line(x='index', y='data', source=df)
show(p)
```

##### Output

[image: applied datetimetickformatter]